# How to efficiently handle European decimal separators using the pandas read_csv function?

Tags: python, csv, decimal, pandas

I'm using `read_csv` to read CSV files into Pandas data frames. My CSV files contain large numbers of decimals/floats. The numbers are encoded using the European decimal notation:

```
1.234.456,78
```

This means that the '.' is used as the thousand separator and the ',' is the decimal mark.

Pandas 0.8. provides a `read_csv` argument called 'thousands' to set the thousand separator. Is there an additional argument to provide the decimal mark as well? If no, what is the most efficient way to parse a European style decimal number?

Currently I'm using string replace which I consider to be a significant performance penalty. The coding I'm using is this:

```
# Convert to float data type and change decimal point from ',' to '.'
f = lambda x: string.replace(x, u',', u'.')
df['MyColumn'] = df['MyColumn'].map(f)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Note this is mentioned in open issues 584 and 781 on GitHub

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert commas to dots within a Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31700691/convert-commas-to-dots-within-a-dataframe)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `converters` kw in `read_csv`. Given `/tmp/data.csv` like this:

```
"x","y"                                                                         
"one","1.234,56"                                                                
"two","2.000,00"
```

you can do:

```
In [20]: pandas.read_csv('/tmp/data.csv', converters={'y': lambda x: float(x.replace('.','').replace(',','.'))})
Out[20]: 
     x        y
0  one  1234.56
1  two  2000.00
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. I'm not sure if the converter function is faster than string.replace. The profiler will tell. ;-)

Comment: Probably the speed will be the same, but using the `converters` you gain the ability of specifying the type of your column.

Answer (score 21):

For European style numbers, use the `thousands` and `decimal` parameters in `pandas.read_csv`.

For example:

```py
pandas.read_csv('data.csv', thousands='.', decimal=',')
```

From the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html):

> **thousands** :
>
> str, optional Thousands separator.
>
> **decimal** :
>
> str, default ‘.’ Character to recognize as decimal point
>   (e.g. use ‘,’ for European data).

Comment: This is currently the correct answer, after Pandas introduced those two arguments to `read_csv` and `to_csv`.