# Problems reading csv-File

Tags: python, pandas

I am having massive issues reading an csv which I can provide upon request (since I don't know how to upload here). It has the dot `.` as thousands separator which makes issues as stated before. Additionally, I need to use `skipfooter=1` since my file has one empty line at the end. This makes the `decimal=","` not to work, even if there is no dot present ...

My files look like this:

```
Commerzbank AG Fakt.3xLongZ.09(09/unl.)CBK(WKN: CZ24PE B<F6>rse: LT Commerzbank)

Datum;Zeit;Er<F6>ffnung;Hoch;Tief;Schluss;Volumen
02.08.2013;14:00;0,033;0,033;0,023;0,028;0,00
01.08.2013;14:00;0,023;0,029;0,022;0,028;0,00
14.03.2013;13:00;0,125;0,125;0,094;0,105;0,00
13.03.2013;13:00;0,165;0,165;0,105;0,125;0,00
```

Don't miss the double empty line at the end not shown here. This makes the use of skipfooter essential, otherwise the date is not recognized correctly. My best try is:

```
s = pd.read_csv('test.csv', decimal=',',sep=';',
                parse_dates={'Dates': [0, 1]},
                index_col=[0], skipfooter=1, skiprows=3)
```

This reads date correct, but all numbers are not recognized.

Regards.

Comment: Please provide sample data. And what have your tried?

Comment: And sample code please. Are you using the `csv` module ?

Comment: Does this answer help with the thousands separator? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11763204/how-to-efficiently-handle-european-decimal-separators-using-the-pandas-read-csv

Comment: Also see this recent (open) github issue: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/4322

Comment: Have you tried adding `thousands="."` to the argument list?

Answer (score 1):

Use nrows instead of skipfooter. The decimal option works with it

```
df = pd.read_csv(fileName, index_col=[indexParam], 
                          skiprows = rowsToSkip,
                          decimal = ',', nrows = rowsToRead)
```