# Convert commas decimal separators to dots within a Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, csv, delimiter, separator

I am importing a CSV file like the one below, using `pandas.read_csv`:

```
df = pd.read_csv(Input, delimiter=";")
```

Example of CSV file:

```
10;01.02.2015 16:58;01.02.2015 16:58;-0.59;0.1;-4.39;NotApplicable;0.79;0.2
11;01.02.2015 16:58;01.02.2015 16:58;-0.57;0.2;-2.87;NotApplicable;0.79;0.21
```

The problem is that when I later on in my code try to use these values I get this error: `TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'`

**The error is because the number I'm trying to use is not written with a dot (`.`) as a decimal separator but a comma(`,`)**. After manually changing the commas to a dots my program works.

I can't change the format of my input, and thus have to replace the commas in my DataFrame in order for my code to work, and I want python to do this without the need of doing it manually. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 164, accepted):

[`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) has a `decimal` parameter for this.

I.e. try with:

```
df = pd.read_csv(Input, delimiter=";", decimal=",")
```

Answer (score 26):

I think the earlier mentioned answer of including `decimal=","` in pandas read_csv is the preferred option.

However, I found it is incompatible with the Python parsing engine. e.g. when using `skiprow=`, read_csv will fall back to this engine and thus you can't use `skiprow=` and `decimal=` in the same read_csv statement as far as I know. Also, I haven't been able to actually get the `decimal=` statement to work (probably due to me though)

The long way round I used to achieving the same result is with list comprehensions, `.replace` and `.astype`. The major downside to this method is that it needs to be done one column at a time:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['120,00', '42,00', '18,00', '23,00'], 
                'b': ['51,23', '18,45', '28,90', '133,00']})

df['a'] = [x.replace(',', '.') for x in df['a']]

df['a'] = df['a'].astype(float)
```

Now, column a will have float type cells. Column b still contains strings.

Note that the `.replace` used here is not pandas' but rather Python's built-in version. Pandas' version requires the string to be an exact match or a regex.

Comment: This workaround is also needed for reading excel files, as `pd.read_excel` doesn't have the `decimal` parameter.

Comment: It can be useful the function `pandas.to_numeric` [docs to_numeric](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) where you can control errors on the conversion instead of `astype(float)`.

Comment: This still seems to be a problem .. so silly.

Comment: Beware!, with this solution, for numbers containing more than one comma, numbers like `2,340,00` become `2,340.00`. Go with @edhaussy answer for peace of mind.

Answer (score 16):

stallasia's answer looks like the best one.

However, if you want to change the separator when you already have a dataframe, you could do :

```
df['a'] = df['a'].str.replace(',', '.').astype(float)
```

Answer (score 8):

Thanks for the great answers. I just want to add that in my case just using `decimal=','` did not work because I had numbers like 1.450,00 (with thousands separator), therefore pandas did not recognize it, but passing `thousands='.'` helped to read the file correctly:

```
df = pd.read_csv(
    Input, 
    delimiter=";", 
    decimal=","
    thousands="."
)
```

Answer (score 5):

I answer to the question about how to change the decimal `comma` to the decimal `dot` with Python Pandas.

```
$ cat test.py 
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("test.csv", quotechar='"', decimal=",")
df.to_csv("test2.csv", sep=',', encoding='utf-8', quotechar='"', decimal='.')
```

where we specify the reading in decimal separator as comma while the output separator is specified as dot. So

```
$ cat test.csv 
header,header2
1,"2,1"
3,"4,0"
$ cat test2.csv 
,header,header2
0,1,2.1
1,3,4.0
```

where you see that the separator has changed to dot.