# Python Pandas: correct way to change comma decimal to dot decimal in Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, decimal

I am looking for the correct way to change the comma decimal separator to the dot decimal separator.

**How can you change the decimal separator from comma `,` to dot `.` with Python Pandas?**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("some.csv", quotechar='"', decimal=",")
decmark_reg = re.compile('(?<=\d),(?=\d)')          #replace all commas with dots
decmark_reg.sub('.', result) # IS THIS CORRECT WAY TO CHANGE DECIMAL Separator?
...
result.to_csv(fileName, sep=',', encoding='utf-8', quotechar='"')
```

**[Apparently a solution]** to change the `,` decimals to the `.` decimals

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("some.csv", quotechar='"', decimal=",")
df.to_csv(fileName, sep=',', encoding='utf-8', quotechar='"', decimal='.')
```

Comment: Seen [Convert commas to dots within a Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31700691/convert-commas-to-dots-within-a-dataframe)?

Comment: `result.to_csv(fileName, sep=',', encoding='utf-8', quotechar='"', decimal=',')`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ so `read_csv()` has the initial decimal separator (here comma) while the `to_csv` has the wanted decimal separator (here dot). Did I understand this right?

Comment: The sep refers to the column separator. I assume your initial csv has a different separator from a comma.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ initial separator is the comma `,` in the file while the wanted separator in the output is the dot `.`. Is the solution in the Q correct?