# ValueError: could not convert string to float: '4,6'

Tags: python, pandas

While reading from csv I have `ValueError: could not convert string to float`. It begins from readng the file, after I give names to columns and remove NaNs.

```
from pandas import read_csv
df = read_csv("propositio/data.csv", header=None, 
    sep=';', decimal=',')
cols = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4']
df.columns = cols
df.dropna(inplace=True)
```

Here comes an error. I want to convert `non-null object` into floats:

```
df = df.astype(float)
```

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: '4,6'

How can I fix it?

Comment: `df = df.str.replace(",", ".").astype(float)` ?

Comment: Not a python expert, but if I read [Rakesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/532312/rakesh)'s suggestion correctly, it matches my assumption - unless your locale handles it, Python is likely expecting the American standard of a decimal point dot rather than a comma. Try that, possibly with Rakesh's code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert commas to dots within a Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31700691/convert-commas-to-dots-within-a-dataframe)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `str.replace` to replace comma with dot

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"A": ['4,6', "5.6", '6,6']})
df = df["A"].str.replace(',', ".").astype(float)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
0    4.6
1    5.6
2    6.6
Name: A, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Why doesn't it know that already from the `decimal=","` specification? Python is so unpythonic in many ways ...

Comment: gives AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'

Comment: You need to mention the column name ex: `df = df["YOUR_COLUMN_NAME"].str.replace(',', ".").astype(float)
`

Comment: or `df = df.stack().str.replace(',','.').unstack()`