# Pandas read_csv import my numeric data as str?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, pandas-datareader

I use pandas tu read a csv fill with numeric data like these:

```
-9999;-11,558;-0,692;0,005;0,001;-1
-9999;-3,32;1,054;5,317;0;-1
...
```

I use this line of code to import:

```
data = pd.read_csv(file, usecols = [0,1,2,3,4], sep = ";", header=None)
```

and the result is all my dataframe is fill by my numeric converted in string ex: '3,4'

I try adding ,dtype=float to my pd.read_csv line but I got this error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '5,04'
```

!!??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the parameters `decimal=","` and `thousands="."` are described in the documentation. they could help

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

```
data = pd.read_csv(file, usecols = [0,1,2,3,4],delimiter=";", decimal=",",thousands=".", header=None)
```

propably solved in https://stackoverflow.com/a/70748012/6889858

Answer (score 2):

you should write `5.04`, the decimal point is required, if it's not in the number it will count as a `tuple`

Answer (score 1):

The decimal point in your numbers is comma. You should pass `decimal=','` as argument to `pandas.read_csv()`.

From [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html):

> **decimalstr**, default ‘.’
>
> ```
> Character to recognize as decimal point (e.g. use ‘,’ for European data).
> ```