# how to handle decimal separator in float using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, decimal

So basically I have a csv file which consists of two columns in which the data are Cinema name and prices respectively. (data in Cinema name are all string whereas prices are float64 but may have example like **12,000.0** OR **3,025.54**  where I want it to be **12000.0** or **3025.54** )
I firstly tried normal read_csv

```
df.read_csv('file')
```

But it turned out that the **float64** was parsed as **Object**, which is not what I want.
I read this [`post`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11763204/how-to-efficiently-handle-european-decimal-separators-using-the-pandas-read-csv), but the solution there is assuming they know the column name and datatype in that column.
Assuming I don't know what the column name will be, how would I efficiently handle comma separator in float and make it into float instead of object ?
**Note** I only want to handle ',' only for float Data not String data.
Thanks for your helps..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) function has a `thousands` argument, which you can specify to be `,` instead of the default `.`

```
df.read_csv('file', thousands=',')
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but this **decimal** breaks only decimal, what I'm saying is 1,000.0 to 1000.0 because first one is recognized as string not float

Comment: Sorry, I wrote `decimals` but meant `thousands`