# Read numbers with exponetial format in python

Tags: python, numpy, import

I have some documents from which I need to process the numerical data, therefore I would like to extract every value and form an array out of it. How can I do that if the formatting of the values is the following:

```
1,234567E+12   1,234567E+12   1,234567E+12   1,234567E+12  
1,234567E+12   1,234567E+12   1,234567E+12   1,234567E+12   
1,234567E+12   1,234567E+12   1,234567E+12   1,234567E+12
```

And the spacing in between the values sometimes varies.

Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

You might find this answer useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56114791/4706413

```
df = pandas.read_csv('data.csv', decimal=',')
```

There are lots of [additional options](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) for `read_csv` that may be useful too.