# Replacing , with . before type casting in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I got a dataframe from a .csv that contains a column with numeric values however they are written using a , instead of a .. I am trying to alter this before casting the value but I am guessing my lack of Python skills is making me make wring assumptions as this does not seem to work.

```
df['score'] = df['score'].replace(',', '.')
df['score'].astype('float64')
```

What is it I am doing wrong here?

Comment: What error do you get? And have you tried `df=pd.read_csv('filename.csv', thousands=',')`

Comment: Try this: `df['score'] = df['score'].replace(',', '.', regex=True)`

Answer (score 2):

As written in https://stackoverflow.com/a/56114791/5666087 and described in the documentation of [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html), you should use

```py
import pandas as pd

pd.read_csv(path_to_csv, decimal=",")
```

The documentation states

> decimal : `str`, default `'.'`
>
> Character to recognize as decimal point (e.g. use `','` for European data).

Here is an example

```py
import io
import pandas as pd

data = """
item,cost
book,"19,99"
coffee,"2,50"
"""

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), decimal=",")
df.head()
#      item   cost
# 0    book  19.99
# 1  coffee   2.50

df.dtypes
# item     object
# cost    float64
# dtype: object
```

Comment: This is what you should do, i.e. parse the data in the csv correctly to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```py
df['score'] = df['score'].apply(lambda x : float(x.replace(',', '.')))
```

or

```py
df['score'] = df['score'].str.replace(',','-')
```

See also [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28986489/how-to-replace-text-in-a-column-of-a-pandas-dataframe)