# How can I parse a string number to a float python

Tags: python

from excel I have a number in the following type: "22.024.833,02 ", so I've been trying .strip(), .replace() among others but I couldn't get a float from my code.

```
for columna, fila in mav.iterrows():
    comitente = fila['Comit.']
    moneda = fila['Especie']
    m = fila['Operado'].strip()
    m2 = m.replace('.', '')
    monto = float(m2)
```

Result:     monto = float(m2)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '22024833,02'

Comment: `'22.024.833,02'.replace('.','').replace(',','.')`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I convert a string with dot and comma into a float in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6633523/how-can-i-convert-a-string-with-dot-and-comma-into-a-float-in-python)

Comment: @Renat, it looks like OP is using the dot for separating digits and the comma for the decimal point, so that answer doesn't quite get there.

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso, it's still a number in a localized format, which is addressed in that question

Comment: @Renat you're correct, I did not see the answer that dealt with this initially when looking at that question

Comment: Answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/56114791/11687201 just set additional parameters for the file reading with pandas.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert a string to a number if it has commas in it as thousands separators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779288/how-to-convert-a-string-to-a-number-if-it-has-commas-in-it-as-thousands-separato)

Answer (score 2):

My answer is assuming you're using `.` for digit separator and `,` for the decimal point.

```
m = fila['Operado'].strip()    # m = "22.024.833,02"
m = m.replace('.', '')         # m = "22024833,02"
m = m.replace(',', '.')        # m = "22024833.02"
monto = float(m)               # monto = 22024833.02
```

Python's `float` expects no digit separator (the `.` in your example), and the decimal point to be a `.` (not a `,` as in your input).

Comment: The answer is about string->float conversion, not about getting a single string from a csv file's row. Btw I found really usefull to read the comments next to your code to better understand what the OP was really asking. +1

Comment: @FLAK-ZOSO You're right, reading from the file is not important at all, I just formatted it this way to align with what was in OPs post.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for

```
m = float(fila['Operado'].strip().replace(".","").replace(",","."))
```

Its better to use `.` for decimal places and `,` for the whole number part.

Comment: I had also tried replacing "," for "." but it didnt work guys, i tried it again and it worked!  I appreciatate your comments , thank you guys!!!

Answer (score 0):

In Python you should use `.` instead of `,` as decimal separator.

```
good_float = 1.44
not_a_float = 1,22 # This will be stored as a tuple
```

If your input string is written with `,` as decimal separator, you can use `String.replace()` method.

```
>>> '3,14'.replace(',', '.')
'3.14'
```

If you are also using `.` as digit separator, you can replace it with the same method.

```
>>> '1.203,14'.replace('.', ' ').replace(',', '.')
'1203,14'
```

Then you can finely convert the string to a float using the `float` built-in function.

```
>>> float('3,14'.replace('.', ' ').replace(',', '.'))
3.14
```

Remember to always write `.replace('.', ' ')` before `.replace(',', '.')` to avoid a mess with periods.

---

Your code should work now:

```
>>> float(fila['Operado'].strip().replace('.', ' ').replace(',', '.'))
```